# What are example use cases for OpenID implicit flow vs standard flow?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, openid, keycloak

In what cases would you use the OpenID Connect Implicit flow:
http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowAuth

Vs the Standard flow?
http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowAuth

Answer (score 3):

The Authorization Code Flow hides the generated token from the user and ensure that only the right client application can access it. It's a three way communication:

1. The user authenticates to the openid provider.
2. The openid provider returns an *authorization code* to the user's browser.
3. The user's browser passes the authorization code to the client application.
4. The client application calls the openid provider with the *authorization code* and with a *client secret* that ensure that it is indeed the client application.
5. The openid provider returns the actual access tokens.

This flow is more secure for server-based applications as the access tokens are never exposed to the client browser. The server application also authenticates itself using the client secret so noone else can use it.

The implicit flow is used when the entire client is run in Javascript in the browser. The javascript client can't keep a "client secret", so there's no use for that and the javascript client should get the tokens available in the browser. The simple solution is to let the openid provider return the access tokens directly to the browser.